# Hide delete link through the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to hide the delete link through the action instead of using `flash[:error]` ?
the admin should delete anyone except himself so what i am asking for is when he view the user list he should not see delete link for himself , and he should see delete link for the other users so he can delete them.

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user?(@user)
      flash[:error] = "Admin suicide warning: Can't delete yourself."
    else
      @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'User deleted'
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: Below answer is fine, but you should restrict this at both levels (Controller & View) as well. you can hide the link from views, but somehow its possible to send request to your destroy method, so its good to keep this code as well. Thanks

Comment: Now i have both current_user == user in view and controller so the current user should not be deleted unless i removed current_user == user from my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'hide it through the action', but the typical way to do this would be to not show the delete link for that user in your view.

Something like:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
 (put delete link for @user here)
<% end %>
```

Comment: right, so my interpretation was correct. Just wrap a conditional around the delete link so that it's not shown for the current user.

Comment: `undefined method 'current_user?'`
I am using devise and in the navbar i have this `<% if user_signed_in? %><%= current_user.user_name %> ... <% end %>` which is working

Comment: you used `current_user?` in your code which is why I used it as well.

Comment: Please use `<% if current_user == @user %>` inspite of `<% unless current_user?(@user)%>`

Comment: Please don't use `if` because that inverts the intended behaviour completely

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_path(@user), method: 'delete' if current_user.id != @user.id %>
```

Comment: `g.column  do |user|
       link_to('Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'You sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-danger")
    end`

i have this and when i put the if condition it raises an error , i am using wicegrid gem